# Concatenar partes dos nomes de variáveis

Tags: php, array

Tenho um ciclo `for`, e quero criar vários *arrays* com o nome diferente do incremento do `for`. Experimento isso, mas não é possível.

```
for($y=0; $y<=1; $y++){
    $newarray_date.$y = array();
    $newarray_time.$y = array();
    $newarray_valeur.$y = array();
}
```

Neste caso o nome do array seria `$newarray_date0` e `$newarray_date1`.

Comment: Ainda não entendi o que você quer velho.... tenta dar uns exemplos pra ver se a pergunta fica mais `entendivel`

Comment: Acho que o que quer não dá para fazer. O que o akm quer é criar variáveis (arrays) com nomes distintos num ciclo. Por exemplo, ali quando `y==0` cria o array com o nome: `$newarray_date0` e quando `y==1` cria o array com o nome `$newarray_date1`

Comment: Então, @akm, tenta dar um exemplo do que você quer fazer, talvez haja outra solução plausivel

Comment: O que você quer é gerar `arrays` dinamicamente?

Comment: Cara acho que entra outro array ai na história `array("date0"=>array()...)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você não pode fazer isso, pelo menos não diretamente. E mesmo com a gambiarra que dá para fazer, ela produzirá um dos códigos mais bizarros que já vi.

Se você chamar todas variáveis do mesmo nome você deve usar um *array* bidimmensional.

```
$newarray_date = array();
$newarray_time = array();
$newarray_valeur = array();
for($y = 0; $y <= 1; $y++){
    $newarray_date[$y] = array();
    $newarray_time[$y] = array();
    $newarray_valeur[$y] = array();
}
```

O que você está fazendo aí é colocar *arrays* dentro em um outro *array*, portando ele simula ter duas dimensões (PHP não possui o conceito real de *array* multidimensional).

Sempre que você quer que um nome de variável varie a solução é criar um índice para este nome e o índice é possível através de *arrays*.

Estão surgindo ideias que usam gambiarras. Eu pensei nas duas que já li aqui. Por favor não usem uma solução complicada e que pode gerar efeitos indesejáveis.

Variáveis variáveis não são variáveis de verdade, completas, elas não podem ser usadas em qualquer situação. Elas subvertem o que se espera de um código normal, elas dificultam a manutenção.

*Arrays* associativos são pelo menos deixa explícito que você não está usando variáveis e sim índices para simular a variável. Mas fica um código esquisito.

Eu não teria problemas em usar qualquer destas soluções se o problema exigisse realmente uma delas. Mas existe uma solução mais simples, fácil, correta e elegante. Então não tem porque não usá-la.

Ainda dá para melhorar ainda mais e tornar tudo isto uma variável só. Tem três soluções possíveis:

1. Criar mais uma dimensão para trara `date`, `time` e `valeur` como índices numéricos. É uma tentativa de otimização mas que não ajuda muito em PHP. Não ajudar identificar bem cada elemento, o código estaria usando números mágicos.
2. Criar uma classe com `date`, `time` e `valeur` como membros dela e usar instâncias desta classe como elemento. Isto inverte um pouco a lógica usada mas me parece que faz mais sentido já que eu entendo que estes três valores são indissociáveis. Estruturas de dados devem ser preferidas nestes casos para dar mais semântica ao código.
3. Cria uma nova dimensão como *array* associativo. Provavelmente a preferida porque ela é menos cerimoniosa que criar uma classe só para isto mantendo uma boa semântica. Ficaria algo assim:

   ```
   $newarray = array();
   for($y = 0; $y <= 1; $y++){
       $newarray[$y]['date'] = array();
       $newarray[$y]['time'] = array();
       $newarray[$y]['valeur'] = array();
   }
   ```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Array/JaggedArray.php).

Comment: Que [a gambiarra](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) fique registrada em letras miúdas então :)

Comment: Boa ideia! :) A pergunta é tão estranha que nem me passou pela cabeça uma resposta tão simples. Mas acho que a ideia do AP é mesmo criar variáveis num ciclo. De qualquer forma é uma ótima ideia. Mais uma vez a resposta salva a pergunta ;)

Comment: @JorgeB. eu estou tão acostumado em ver códigos malucos que eu pego essas intenções logo.

Comment: @bfavaretto espero que os *ups* no seu comentário sejam para só a parte das letras miúdas :)

Comment: @bigown ai vai aquela pergunta chata que todo programador se faz um dia.... devemos ir pelo caminho mais fácil, ou pelo caminho mais correto?

Porque o mais fácil às vezes também parece ser o mais correto na maioria dos casos

Comment: eu já vi essa gambiarra sendo usada no lugar do `extract`. Tipo assim `foreach($array as $key => $value){ $$key = $value; }`